# Anonymous account on Firebase is not persistent (recreated every few hours)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

In my android app I offer the ability for users to add content. The user signs in anonymously on Firebase and their content is linked to their anonymous UID.
Unfortunately the anonymous account on Firebase is not persistent (every few hours a user is assigned a new UID thus loosing the ability to edit their own sets).

I execute the following logic every time the MainActivity is created:

```
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    if(auth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        Log.d("Test", "Logging in anonymously");
        auth.signInAnonymously().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("Test", "Anonymous Login success");
                }else{
                    Log.d("Test", "Anonymous Login failed");
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error while creating anonymous account", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }else{
        Log.d("Test", "Already Logged-In");
    }
```

How can I achieve that the anonymous accounts is permanent per device installation?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.  Are you observing some problem with the way the code works?  Please edit the question to be specific about what's not working the way you expect, or what specifically you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Hmmm.... that sounds weird. The `auth.signInAnonymously()` is supposed to restore the existing user as far as I know. Can you test something: 1) only use `auth.signInAnonymously()` on the first run to create the user, 2) then on secondary runs use [`auth.addAuthStateListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth#addAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)) to pick up the restored state and see if that works.